# How to change command prompt screen height limit beyond 9999?

Tags: windows, command-prompt

I am running a code in which the output is so long and it 9999 limit of the command prompt is not enough to show all my output. is there a way to increase this limit?

Comment: no you can't do that with conhost.exe (the default terminal for cmd and powershell). You have to use another terminal. And this has nothing to do with programming so it's off-topic. Duplicate: [Windows command line window scroll limit](https://superuser.com/q/1526097/241386)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Like phuclv said, there isn't. Any output that large you should redirect to a file `command > file`.

Comment: it's useful for scrolling back when you don't know in prior the length of the output. And it's related to the terminal, not the shells (like powershell or cmd). The shells just pass the output stream to the terminal for displaying. Most Linux terminals support infinite scrolling and many of them has been ported to Windows